freecodecamp.org notes not appearing issue
I have been following flutter course provided by freecodecamp.org, and the notes I have written are not being rendered in the notes view
the code lies below. there must be something I am missing or concepts I may have overlooked but either way, I am unable to get the expected result.
In the debug console I am given this:
    E/SQLiteLog(28060): (1) no such table: note in "INSERT INTO note (user_id, text,  is_synced_with_cloud) VALUES   (?, ?, ?)"

   Notes_view

    //import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:lambo/constants/routes.dart';
    import 'package:lambo/enums/menu_action.dart';
    import 'package:lambo/services/auth/auth_service.dart';
    import 'package:lambo/services/auth/crud/notes__service.dart';

    class NotesView extends StatefulWidget {
      const NotesView({super.key});

      @override
      State<NotesView> createState() => _NotesViewState();
    }

    class _NotesViewState extends State<NotesView> {

      late final NotesService _notesService;
      String get userEmail => AuthService.firebase().currentUser!.email!;
      
      @override
      void initState() {
        _notesService = NotesService();
        super.initState();
      } 

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            title: const Text('Notes', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(newNoteRoute);
                }, 
                icon: const Icon(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  Icons.add
                  )
                ),
              PopupMenuButton<MenuAction>(
                onSelected: (value) async{
                  switch(value) {
                    case MenuAction.logout:
                      final shouldLogout = await showLogOutDialog(context);
                      if (shouldLogout == true) {
                        await AuthService.firebase().logOut();
                        Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                          loginRoute, 
                          (_) => false,
                        );
                      }
                  }
                }, 
                icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert, color: Colors.white,),
                itemBuilder: (context) {
                return const [
                  PopupMenuItem<MenuAction>(
                    value: MenuAction.logout,
                    child: Text('Log out'),
                  ),
                ];
              },
              )
            ], 
          ),
          body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _notesService.getOrCreateUser(email: userEmail), 
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.done:
                return StreamBuilder(
                  stream: _notesService.allNotes, 
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                      case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      case ConnectionState.active:
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        final allNotes = snapshot.data as List<DatabaseNote>;
                        return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: allNotes.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            final note = allNotes[index];
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text (
                                note.text
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      } else {
                        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }
                      default:
                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
                  });
              default:
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            }
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    Future<bool> showLogOutDialog(BuildContext context){
      return showDialog<bool>(
        context: context, 
        builder: (context){
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Log out'),
            content: const Text('Are you sure you want ot log out ?'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
              }, child: const Text('Cancel')),
              TextButton(onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
              }, child: const Text('Log out')),
            ],
          );
        },
      ).then((value) => value ?? false);
    }

Notes_service
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:lambo/services/auth/crud/crud_exceptions.dart';
    import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
    import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
    import 'package:path/path.dart' show join;


    class NotesService {
      Database? _db;

      List<DatabaseNote> _notes = [];
      
      
      static final NotesService _shared = NotesService._sharedInstance();
      NotesService._sharedInstance() {
        _notesStreamController = StreamController<List<DatabaseNote>>.broadcast(
          onListen: () {
            _notesStreamController.sink.add(_notes);
          },
        );
      }
      factory NotesService() => _shared;

      late final StreamController<List<DatabaseNote>> _notesStreamController;

      Stream<List<DatabaseNote>> get allNotes => _notesStreamController.stream;

      Future<DatabaseUser> getOrCreateUser({required String email}) async {
        try {
          final user = await getUser(email: email);
          return user;
        } on CouldNotFindUser {
          final createdUser = await createUser(email: email);
          return createdUser;
        } catch (e) {
          rethrow; 
        }
      }

      Future<void> _cacheNotes() async {
        final allNotes = await getAllNotes();
        _notes = allNotes.toList();
        _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
      }

      Future<DatabaseNote> updateNote({
        required DatabaseNote note,
        required String text,
      }) async {
        await _ensureDbIsOpen();
        final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
        
        await getNote(id: note.id);
        final updatesCount = await db.update(noteTable, {
          textColumn: text,
          isSyncedWithCloudColumn: 0,
        });
        if (updatesCount == 0) {
          throw CouldNotUpdateNote();
        } else {
          final updatedNote = await getNote(id: note.id);
          _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == updatedNote.id);
          _notes.add(updatedNote);
          _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
          return updatedNote;
        }
      }

      Future<Iterable<DatabaseNote>> getAllNotes() async {
        await _ensureDbIsOpen();
        final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
        final notes = await db.query(noteTable);
        return notes.map((noteRow) => DatabaseNote.fromRow(noteRow));
      }

      Future<DatabaseNote> getNote({required int id}) async {
        await _ensureDbIsOpen();
        final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
        final notes = await db.query(
          noteTable, 
          limit: 1, 
          where: 'id = ?', 
          whereArgs: [id]
        );
        if (notes.isEmpty) {
          throw CouldNotFindNote();
        } else {
          final note = DatabaseNote.fromRow(notes.first);
          _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == id);
          _notes.add(note);
          _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
          return note;
        }
      }

      Future<int> deleteAllNotes() async {
        await _ensureDbIsOpen();
        final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
        final numberOfDeletions = await db.delete(noteTable);
        _notes = [];
        _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
      return numberOfDeletions;
      }

      Future<void> deleteNote({required int id}) async {
        await _ensureDbIsOpen();
        final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
        final deletedCount = await db.delete(
          userTable,
          where: 'id = ?',
          whereArgs: [id],
        );
        if (deletedCount == 0) {
          throw CouldNotDeleteNote();
        } else {
          _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == id);
          _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
        }
      }

      Future<DatabaseNote> createNote({required DatabaseUser owner}) async {
        await _ensureDbIsOpen();
        final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();

        //make sure owner exists in the database iwth correct id
        final dbUser = await getUser(email: owner.email);
        if (dbUser != owner) {
          throw CouldNotFindUser();
        }
        const text = '';
        // create the note
        final noteId = await db.insert(noteTable, {
          userIdColumn: owner.id,
          textColumn: text,
          isSyncedWithCloudColumn: 1
        });
        final note = DatabaseNote(
          id: noteId, 
          userId: owner.id, 
          text: text, 
          isSyncedWithCloud: true
        );

        _notes.add(note);
        _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
        return note;
      }

      Future<DatabaseUser> getUser({required String email}) async {
        await _ensureDbIsOpen();
        final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
        final results = await db.query(
          userTable,
          limit: 1,
          where: 'email = ?',
          whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()]
        );
        if (results.isEmpty) {
          throw CouldNotFindUser();
        } else {
          return DatabaseUser.fromRow(results.first);
        }
      }

      Future<DatabaseUser> createUser({required String email}) async {
        await _ensureDbIsOpen();
        final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
        final results = await db.query(
          userTable,
          limit: 1,
          where: 'email = ?',
          whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()] 
        );
        if (results.isNotEmpty) {
          throw UserAlreadyExists();
        }

        final userId = await db.insert(userTable, {
          emailColumn: email.toLowerCase(),
        });

        return DatabaseUser(
          id: userId, 
          email: email,
        );
      }

      Future<void> deleteUser({required String email}) async {
        await _ensureDbIsOpen();
        final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
        final deletedCount = await db.delete(
          userTable,
          where: 'email = ?',
          whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
        );
        if (deletedCount != 1) {
          throw CouldNotDeleteUser();
        }
      }

      Database _getDatabaseOrThrow() {
        final db = _db;
        if (db == null) {
          throw DatabaseIsNotOpen();
        } else {
          return db;
        }
      }

      Future<void> close() async {
      final db = _db;
      if (db == null) {
        throw DatabaseIsNotOpen();
      } else {
        await db.close();
        _db = null;
      }
    }

    Future<void> _ensureDbIsOpen() async {
      try {
        await open();
      } on DatabaseAlreadyOpenException {
        //empty
      }
    }

      Future<void> open() async {
        if (_db != null) {
          throw DatabaseAlreadyOpenException();
        }
        try {
          final docsPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
          final dbpath = join(docsPath.path, dbName);
          final db = await openDatabase(dbpath);
          _db = db;

        await db.execute(createUserTable);

        await db.execute(createNoteTable);
        await _cacheNotes();
        } on MissingPlatformDirectoryException{
          throw UnableToGetDocumentDirectory();
        }
      }
    }

    @immutable
    class DatabaseUser {
      final int id;
      final String email;
      const DatabaseUser({
        required this.id,
        required this.email,
      });
      
      DatabaseUser.fromRow(Map<String, Object?> map) : 
      id = map[idColumn] as int, 
      email = map[emailColumn] as String;

    @override 
    String toString() => 'person, ID = $id, email = $email';

    @override bool operator == (covariant DatabaseUser other) => id == other.id;

    @override
      int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
    }

    class DatabaseNote{
      final int id;
      final int userId;
      final String text;
      final bool isSyncedWithCloud;

      DatabaseNote({
        required this.id, 
        required this.userId, 
        required this.text, 
        required this.isSyncedWithCloud
        });

        DatabaseNote.fromRow(Map<String, Object?> map) : 
      id = map[idColumn] as int, 
      userId = map[userIdColumn] as int,
      text = map[textColumn] as String,
      isSyncedWithCloud = (map[isSyncedWithCloudColumn] as int) == 1 ? true : false;

      @override 
      String toString() =>
      'Note, ID = $id, userId = $userId, isSyncedWithCloud = $isSyncedWithCloud, text = $text';

      @override bool operator == (covariant DatabaseUser other) => id == other.id;

    @override
      int get hashCode => id.hashCode;

    }

    const dbName = 'notes.db';
    const noteTable = 'note';
    const userTable = 'user';
    const idColumn = 'id';
    const emailColumn = 'email';
    const userIdColumn = 'user_id';
    const textColumn = 'text';
    const isSyncedWithCloudColumn = 'is_synced_with_cloud';
    const createUserTable = ''' CREATE TABLE "user" (
          "id"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
          "email"   TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
          PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
        ); ''';
    const createNoteTable = ''' CREATE TABLE "note" (
          "id"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
          "user_id" INTEGER NOT NULL COLLATE UTF16CI,
          "text"    INTEGER,
          "is_synced_with_cloud"    INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
          PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT),
          FOREIGN KEY("user_id") REFERENCES "user"("id")
        ); ''';

